# Planck's Formula and Spectral Irradiance

Tags: thermal-radiation

this might seem like a really stupid question but I have spent around 2 hours to understand this but still I was not successful so I wanted to ask.

I have to calculate and ploth a graph of spectral irradiance vs wavelength.

Now I know the plancks formula, which gives the Energy per wavelength. However, I could not figure out how to convert such information to spectral irradiance.

From my understanding, the planck's formula gives a result in "Joules" and we must convert that data to "Watts per meter square per nanometer". And from joule to watt conversion includes division with time, as Watt is a unit for power.

[image: Formula I used for deriving the energy from wavelength.]

Could you please help me making the conversion from energy to spectral irradiance?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), Planck's formula is
$$B_\lambda(\lambda,T)=\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{hc}{\lambda k_BT}\right)-1}$$
It gives you the power emitted at a given wavelength per unit solid angle (1 steradian), per unit area  : W m$^{-1}$ sr$^{-1}$ m$^{-2}$ . You can obtain the spectral irradiance that you described by simply averaging over the solid angle, which adds a factor of $4\pi$ :
$$I_\lambda(\lambda,T)=\frac{8\pi hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{hc}{\lambda k_BT}\right)-1}$$

**Edit : Explanation and terminology**

This differs from the formula in your figure by a factor of $c$.  By dimensionnal analysis, removing a factor of $c$ changes the units of the expression **from** W m$^{-1}$ m$^{-2}$ **to** J m$^{-1}$ m$^{-3}$ (I am separating the meter units to highlight that one of them represents unit wavelength).  So, the formula I wrote represents power per unit area (flux density or **irradiance**) per unit wavelength, while yours is energy per unit volume (**energy density**) per unit wavelength.

Comment: The problem is, when I calculate according to the formula with only one c at the top, it gives a result of **297798.0648643066** for wavelength of 1 micro meter.

However, when I compare my results with the graphs on the internet, or the one on this website [link](http://www.spectralcalc.com/blackbody_calculator/blackbody.php), what I find does not match with what they have there.

I have run the numbers many times, with extra factor of c or without it, I still can not understand where is the problem.

Comment: Well, when I tried to run the numbers with the formula you have shared above (the one with 2hc^2), it gave me the correct results according to the graph as well as the data I found on the internet. Now the problem is, this is the first time I am seeing a formula with c^2

Comment: @OsmanKuzucu Both formulas, with and without $c$ are correct, but they mean different things.  See my edited answer above.